# Window's 10 version 1803 icons won't load bug

Tags: windows

I've having an issue with my installation where after a while my icons and thumbnails just randomly stop loading until I restart.  This seems to only occur when I open a large folder full of images: It seems that if I load too many icons it just randomly stops working.  It still tries though, I can hear my fan speeding up whenever this happens.  I've tried deleting the thumbnails cache file before but it didn't work.  What else could be causing this, and can I either fix it or at least "reset" the issue without having to restart?

EDIT: It turns out that a process called dllhost.exe is causing the issue, if I restart it the problem goes away until the next time.  I'm guessing something is wrong with one of my codecs, it seems to break when trying to load the thumbnail for a specific codec type if it's in the current folder I'm in.

Comment: Have you tried to restart File Explorer?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: If you boot into a minimal boot configuration does the behavior still exhibit itself.  What icon overlays do you have installed? (i.e Dropbox, Google Drive, One Drive, etc) edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Have you tried waiting for it to finish loading the thumbnails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's some webms that VLC media player couldn't generate thumbnails for. This doesn't happen for every webm though, and it can still play those webms fine. I was able to resolve the issue by setting the default webm opener to a different program.